# How to change button size depending on screen size?

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have an image button. What is the way to change its size according to the screen size?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/infobutton"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/info_button" />
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: Is info_button an image? If it is an image you can create different images for different screens drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdp and make layout_width , layout_height to wrap content  Supporting multiple screens :http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: And if it's not, you can make custom dimension in your dimen.xml file that takes 1 value for phones and another for tablets. (for example, the default margin used almost everywhere is 16dp for small sized devices, and 64dp for bigger sized devices). You can copy that behavior.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is a bit involved, so bear with me.

You can create some methods like so..

```
public static int getScreenDensity(Context context) {
    int density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

    switch(density)
    {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH;

        default:
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

Then in an activity you can detect the screen size and adjust button's properties like so.

```
private void setTunerPopoverSize( PopoverView popoverView ) {
    int screenDensity = Util.getScreenDensity( this );

    if (screenDensity == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
        // set button size here if high density
    }  else if (screenDensity == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
        // set button size here if xhigh density
    } else {
        // set default button size
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: your `getScreenDensity` method looks funny :)

Comment: also, screen density != screen size ;)

Comment: I copied and pasted from another program I wrote.   I took all of the actual working code out.  If something doesn't look right I must have deleted too much code.  I will look over and correct if I messed something up.